# Tensorflow example with own handwritten images

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have tried the tensorflow example with zalando mnist here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification

After that I changed the clothes images with handwritten mnist database, which also works.

Now I want to train the AI with the mnist handwritten database, take a picture from my handwritten "1" and let the KI guess the number.

I appended after the trainig of the KI some lines of code.
What I tried is this:

```
ownPicArr = imageio.imread(filename) #it is a 28x28 PNG file
ownPicArr = ownPicArr / 255.0
pred = model.predict(ownPicArr)
```

I got following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (28, 28)
```

How to solve this problem? Thnak you...

Comment: seems that your input has the wrong dimension (28x28 like the png). You need to reshape the input in the same way as done with the training data. Hard to tell what the exact problem is without seeing the code.

Comment: Hi Peter. It is the Code in the link above with my appended lines of code.

Comment: ah... I see: did you try this from the example code # Add the image to a batch where it's the only member.
img = (np.expand_dims(img,0))... „So even though we're using a single image, we need to add it to a list:“

print(img.shape)

Comment: Thank you very much, Peter. That's it. Now I realized, that the colors of my pic are inverted. Got to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the colours of your picture were inverted, this is how you could perform the predictions using OpenCV

```
import os, cv2
image=cv2.imread(imagePath)
image_from_array = Image.fromarray(image, 'RGB')
size_image = image_from_array.resize((28,28))
p = np.expand_dims(size_image, 0)
img = tf.cast(p, tf.float32)
pred = model.predict(img)
```

First we read the image using OpenCV, which stores it as an array. We then convert the array and also specify the colour channels. After Resizing the image we create a batch of a single image and then after changing the datatype to float32 to or the datatype matching your model we finally make predictions